# Store pandas dataframe data to variables in python - ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and have trawled stackoverflow for answers on this, but still can't seem to make it work - despite seeing many references to the problem.

I have a dataframe containing two moving average columns MA13 and MA48. I want to iterate through the dataframe subtracting one from the other on each row and use the result to perform various operations - as per the code below:

positions=0
for row in df.iterrows():

```
if (df['13MA'] > df['48MA'])and positions == 0:
        positions==1
        print('Buy')
    elif (df['13MA'] <= df['48MA']) and positions==1:
        positions==0
        print('Sell')
```

I keep getting the error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Is anyone able to suggest the correct code please as I'm struggling to get my mind around how to reference the dataframe vector?

Many thks

Comment: Like this? `df['Result'] = np.where(df[ (df['positions'] == 0) & (df['13MA'] > df['48MA']) ], 1, np.where(df[ (df['positions'] == 1) & (df['13MA'] <= df['48MA']) ], 0, -1))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that the comparison returns a Series of booleans, and so as the error indicates the truth value is ambiguous. For example

```
>import pandas as pd
>df = pd.DataFrame({'13MA':[1,5,3],'48MA':[0,7,2]})
>df['13MA'] > df['48MA']
0    True
1    False
2    True
dtype: bool

if df['13MA'] > df['48MA']:
    print("Hello")
```

Since this is an array on values, some of which may be True or False, the class throws an error to highlight the ambiguity

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

From the logic in your post it looks like this could likely be vectorized, in which case you could just do something like

```
>positions = df['13MA'] > df['48MA']
>positions = positions.apply(int)
```

Comment: Thks a lot for the feedback. Just managed to solve the problem by changing iterrows statement -> for index,row in df1.iterrows():